# "Value of optional type Self? not unwrapped" inside failable initializer with "try?" and "Self", how to write without force unwrapping

Tags: json, swift, error-handling, codable

I'm trying to add JSON deserializing functionality inside my protocols, but I can't get the `decode` function to compile. How do I write the initializer without forcibly unwrapping the value?

```
protocol Mappable: Codable {
  init?(jsonString: String)
}

extension Mappable {
  init?(jsonString: String) {
    guard let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) else {
        return nil
    }
    // TODO:- Value of optional type 'Self?' not unwrapped error
    self = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: data)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`try?` returns an optional. But in a failable initializer, you don't assign `nil` to `self`, you `return nil`.

The following works:

```
extension Mappable {
    init?(jsonString: String) {
        guard let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) else {
            return nil
        }

        do {
            self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

As others have stated, a few other things to consider:

1. `String data(using:)` with an encoding of `.utf8` can't fail so the `guard` can be replaced with a forced-unwrapped.
2. Consider changing this from a failable initializer to one that throws.

Comment: What's the purpose of it returning optional if it can't ever fail? Or that's because _other_ types of encoding can fail? In that's the case, then it wouldn't it have been better if each encoding had its _own_ function. So some can return non-`nil` type while others can return `nil`?

Comment: @Honey `data(using:)` can fail, just not with the UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

A throwable initializer would work better here:

```
protocol Mappable: Codable {
    init(jsonString: String) throws
}

extension Mappable {
    init(jsonString: String) throws {
        let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)! // this will never be nil
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: data)
    }
}
```

This way your protocol doesn't swallow errors and callers can simply use `try?` on their side, if they don't care about the error.